# How can I optimize a BigQuery query that is insanely large due to a custom dimension?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have this query that pulls exactly what I need it to, but is incredibly large. When I pull it into Tableau (as I need to do), it times out most of the time. Is there any way to optimize this query so that it is not so slow / smaller?

```
SELECT
  date,
  'iOS' as app_source,
  (SELECT value from UNNEST(h.customDimensions) WHERE index=4) as user_id,
  h.eventinfo.eventlabel,
  COUNT(*) as events
FROM
   `ga_ios_table`,
  UNNEST(hits) h
WHERE
  h.type='EVENT'
  and (
  (h.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Live' and h.eventInfo.eventAction = 'Chat' and h.eventInfo.eventLabel = 'Team Chat')
  or (h.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Live' and h.eventInfo.eventAction = 'Photo' and h.eventInfo.eventLabel = 'Team Chat')
  or (h.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Messages' and h.eventInfo.eventAction = 'Chat' and h.eventInfo.eventLabel = 'Direct Message')
  or (h.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Messages' and h.eventInfo.eventAction = 'Chat' and h.eventInfo.eventLabel = 'Group Message')
  or (h.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Messages' and h.eventInfo.eventAction = 'Chat' and h.eventInfo.eventLabel = 'Team Message')
  or (h.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Messages' and h.eventInfo.eventAction = 'Chat' and h.eventInfo.eventLabel = 'Team Message Includes Photo')
  or (h.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Messages' and h.eventInfo.eventAction = 'Chat' and h.eventInfo.eventLabel = 'Group Message Includes Photo')
  or (h.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Messages' and h.eventInfo.eventAction = 'Chat' and h.eventInfo.eventLabel = 'Direct Message Includes Photo')
  )
  and date >= "20180101"
GROUP BY
  1,2,3,4

UNION ALL

SELECT
  date,
  'Android' as app_source,
  (SELECT value from UNNEST(h.customDimensions) WHERE index=4) as user_id,
  h.eventinfo.eventlabel,
  COUNT(*) as events
FROM
   `ga_android_table`,
  UNNEST(hits) h
WHERE
  h.type='EVENT'
  and (
  (h.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Live' and h.eventInfo.eventAction = 'New Chat' and h.eventInfo.eventLabel = 'Team Chat')
  or (h.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Live' and h.eventInfo.eventAction = 'New Photo' and h.eventInfo.eventLabel = 'Team Chat')
  or (h.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Messages' and h.eventInfo.eventAction = 'Chat' and h.eventInfo.eventLabel = 'Direct Message')
  or (h.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Messages' and h.eventInfo.eventAction = 'Chat' and h.eventInfo.eventLabel = 'Group Message')
  or (h.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Messages' and h.eventInfo.eventAction = 'Chat' and h.eventInfo.eventLabel = 'Direct Message Includes Photos')
  or (h.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Messages' and h.eventInfo.eventAction = 'Chat' and h.eventInfo.eventLabel = 'Group Message Includes Photos')
  or (h.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Messages' and h.eventInfo.eventAction = 'Chat' and h.eventInfo.eventLabel = 'Team Message')
  )
  and date >= "20180101"
GROUP BY
   1,2,3,4
```

Comment: It will be important to delimit if the timeout is happening in BigQuery (e.g. Tableau waits long time for Bigquery to finish the job) or Tableau takes long time to transfer the data results that BigQuery delivers (e.g. BQ could be finishing the job in the range of seconds). You can check the time spent by BQ from the BQ UI and searching for the correlated query/job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't really see room for much improvement - rather than making some part of query less verbose as in example below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  DATE,
  'iOS' AS app_source,
  (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(h.customDimensions) WHERE index=4) AS user_id,
  h.eventinfo.eventlabel,
  COUNT(*) AS events
FROM
   `ga_ios_table`,
  UNNEST(hits) h
WHERE
  h.type='EVENT' 
  AND (
    (h.eventInfo.eventCategory, h.eventInfo.eventAction, h.eventInfo.eventLabel) IN (
      ('Live', 'Chat', 'Team Chat'),
      ('Live', 'Photo', 'Team Chat'),
      ('Messages', 'Chat', 'Direct Message'),
      ('Messages', 'Chat', 'Group Message'),
      ('Messages', 'Chat', 'Team Message'),
      ('Messages', 'Chat', 'Team Message Includes Photo'),
      ('Messages', 'Chat', 'Group Message Includes Photo'),
      ('Messages', 'Chat', 'Direct Message Includes Photo')
    )
  )
  AND DATE >= "20180101"
GROUP BY
  1,2,3,4

UNION ALL

SELECT
  DATE,
  'Android' AS app_source,
  (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(h.customDimensions) WHERE index=4) AS user_id,
  h.eventinfo.eventlabel,
  COUNT(*) AS events
FROM
   `ga_android_table`,
  UNNEST(hits) h
WHERE
  h.type='EVENT' 
  AND (
    (h.eventInfo.eventCategory, h.eventInfo.eventAction, h.eventInfo.eventLabel) IN (
      ('Live', 'New Chat', 'Team Chat'),
      ('Live', 'New Photo', 'Team Chat'),
      ('Messages', 'Chat', 'Direct Message'),
      ('Messages', 'Chat', 'Group Message'),
      ('Messages', 'Chat', 'Direct Message Includes Photos'),
      ('Messages', 'Chat', 'Group Message Includes Photos'),
      ('Messages', 'Chat', 'Team Message')
    )
  )
  AND DATE >= "20180101"
GROUP BY
   1,2,3,4
```

I don't have way to test if above will improve your situation - but sometimes less verbose and more compact syntax helps!